# Redirect to HTTP non-www to HTTPS www htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from any direction to our site with HTTPS protocol, but some redirects it's not working. I want this:

- `http://www.site.co` TO `https://www.site.co`
- `http://site.co` TO `https://www.site.co`

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The second rule it's not working. It going to another direction inside our site, and it isn't redirect to HTTPS site.

Comment: [Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider reading **the SO Tour**. it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess for redirecting non-www to www while preserving http & https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525348/htaccess-for-redirecting-non-www-to-www-while-preserving-http-https)

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Prix. I try that response but didn't work for me. I don't know what is the problem actually

Comment: Where is the second rule redirecting to?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal It is not redirect. It show a page intermediate that says something like this: "This is not the oficial page. We redirect to..." and after 5 seconds redirect to https page. The page is: https://www.systemico.co. To show the error that I say you could enter http://systemico.co

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that when using CDN, the CDN could also perform redirects.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The only real difference here is that first we redirect from non-WWW to WWW then we check for HTTPS and redirect it.

If it does not work, try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi @Prix, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately still not working for me. Maybe it could be a problem of configuration the virtual host. It could be???

Comment: @AnibalMauricio are u sure there is nothing else on your htaccess or php that would cause this ?

Comment: well, I just figured out that that page is the default page of apache, so the problem it must be the virtual hosts configuration, right?

Comment: @AnibalMauricio if the document root is different then yes its possible.

Comment: that's it. The problem was in the virtual hosts and dns service. I apreciate all your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: The second option worked better in my case. I've used it in OpenCart. Non-www redirects to https + www, and `https://site.tld` redirects to `https://www.site.tld`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for `%{SERVER_PORT} !^443$` this SSL check! `%{HTTPS} off` was creating infinite redirects for me for some reason

Comment: still getting an infinite loop -.- @bizzz

Comment: @Prix what does $1  represent?

Comment: @Jun https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/images/rewrite_backreferences.png

Comment: @Prix Thanks. I found this link and it seems that $1 is the first match that it finds using this regex: ^(.*)$
In this case, https://example.com/example.html will be redirected to https://www.example.com/example.html, is that right?

But paths in an Angular project, for example, could be 
https://www.example.com/example-one
in that case, this regex won't work, right?
I am trying to understand

Comment: this regex is to simple change from www.domain to domain and switch from http to https regardless of the entire address used, nothing else. If your case is different you should open a new question and explain it so people can provide you with a proper answer.

Comment: the other answer by @Alvin seems to work for my case using Angular.

Comment: This does not seem ideal, it seems to redirect a url like `http://www.example.com/test/` to `http://www.example.com//test/`. An extra slash seems to be added.

Comment: this does not redirect from http to http so you're either misusing it or using it for a purpose its not intended. Also keep in mind this is to solve the OP problem and will not apply to all other cases as its a specific answer which can be different to others depending on what you have, like frameworks in place that also do inner redirect and such.

Comment: SEO tip: to avoid double 301, use http -> https redirect first, then non www -> www

Answer (score 31):

The answer by Prix works. To make it more dynamic lets use SERVER_NAME and REQUEST_URI instead of a static domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On
#we replace domain.com/$1 with %{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#here we dont use www as non www was already redirected to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But if my URL is `https://example.com/page` it does not redirect to WWW. Any ideas?

Comment: This works for angular project that has path like url such as www.example.com/page-one

Answer (score 5):

Sorry I don't have enough point to comment, but the rule of @prix will bring unneeded redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You can try http://domain.com/ on GTMETRIX and you will get this message

```
 "Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs."

http://domain.com/
http://www.domain.com/
https://www.domain.com/
```

To prevent that, go to the first RewriteRule and add a "s" at the end of http. The new set of rule will look like this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is **http to https** and **non www to www redirection** using **.htaccess**

If you want to redirect to https and www you can use this code

**http to https redirection:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Non www to www redirection:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

If you want to use booth functionality place the above all code respectively

Comment: Is it better if we combine them under one `RewriteEngine On` statement in one `<IfModule>` section?

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using One.com as your webhost you should use the following code instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this methode:

```
# Redirect 301 all to https://www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
   RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Why sometimes you don't need code **%{HTTP_HOST}** and use your domain exact url with www for the last line, because usually the result will have two www like:

```
https://www.www.yourdomain.com
```

Btw if you use cloudflare, just create pagerules redirect 301 all to https and www version.

Create pagerules
Fill with

```
example.com/*
```

Choose setting forward url then choose 301 and fill with this

```
https://www.example.com/$1
```

Save it and all will be redirected to https and www version.

Answer (score 1):

I have an asp.net website and the host provider is not supporting IIS rewrite module i have tested all this methods and only this code gives woorank.com confirmation maybe useful for another .net developer :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use for both www or non-www
If you try to open link with www then url redirect to https with www

```
Example : http://domain.com redirect to https://domain.com
```

or If you try to open link with non-www then url redirect to https with non-www

```
Example : http://www.domain.com redirect to https://www.domain.com

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following in the `.htaccess` file

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

For example https://example.com should be going to https://www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Note - you should change example.com to your own domain.

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds over the existing answers - but is there any reason you can't just use example.com and www.example.com ?