# htaccess - redirect non-www to https with www

Tags: .htaccess

I recently switched from a windows server to godaddy,linux,cpanel server. I'm not goos with htaccess and I think this should be a rather simple thing to do but I can't get it right.

My SSL Certificate is set up to work on the site like this: https:www.mydomain.com but not for the (non-www site).

I'd like all traffic coming to https:example.com/any-folder/any-file redirected to https:www.example.com/any-folder/any-file

all traffic coming to http:example.com/any-folder/any-file redirected to http:www.example.com/any-folder/any-file

Thanks for any help you can provide.
This is my htaccess file now: (all request are getting redirected to https.... I'm confused)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect to HTTP non-www to HTTPS www htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453412/redirect-to-http-non-www-to-https-www-htaccess)

Comment: I tried the possible duplicate but all url redirect to https .  here is whaty I tried:

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: As you notice, code in comments does not really work. Instead edit the question if you have additional information ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

will rewrite all request that lack `www.` to `http://www.example.com/$1`. Also for HTTPs requests. This rewrite will result in a new request, since it is a redirect, what you've defined with `[R]`.

After that, the next rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

will redirect all request that are not HTTPs to  `https://www.example.com/$1`. Even if the original request was not supposed to be HTTPs.

You have to do it somehow like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still one problem.

https://example.com does not redirect to https://www.example.com so page displays with certificate error. 

**** Having problem with reply  the first 2 urls should start with https .... It doesn't show when displayed as a link *****  sorry

http://example.com does redirect to http://www.example.com though.

Comment: Did you clean you browser cache before you tested this? I recommend to test rewrite rule changes always in new private browsing tabs, because your browser will cache this redirects.