# Conflicting multiple redirect rules in htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect the site ip to my site `https` as well as i want to redirect the non-www urls to `www` urls. i have written these two rules but they are conflicting. Here is my cade :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#Redirect ip to site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.pk/$1 [L,R=301]

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.pk/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453412/redirect-to-http-non-www-to-https-www-htaccess

Comment: @Damien, individual cases working fine, but together both, not working

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you getting a redirect loop or what?

Comment: Why not put the www rule first and add an [NC] after it?

Comment: @Damien, I tried it too. but when i open ip, it redirects to "https://domain.pk/https:/www.domain.pk/"

Comment: @starkeen, either `https://www.` or just "https://domain.pk/https:/www.domain.pk/".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this with this configuration?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx\.xx\.xxx\.xxx$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.pk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```