# How can I redirect domain name in http without www to https?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vhosts

I want to redirect `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. My application is developed in Laravel framework version 4.2

By following instructions given in following link I have editted my .htaccess file by following given link. But it is not working
[link of suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453412/redirect-to-http-non-www-to-https-www-htaccess)

Complete code in .htaccess file is given below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On



# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond 

%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

My http-vhost file also given below

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\example"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl/example.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl/example.key"
    ErrorDocument 404 "ERROR 404 : PAGE NOT FOUND"  
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common  
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\example">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Why? Generally you don't want two (sub)domains pointing to the same site. It's considered duplicate content.

Comment: I just want secure website only. But when I enter example.com that redirects to unsecure site http://example.com. So I tried to redirect http to https