# How to redirect domain.com or www.domain.com to https www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I want to redirect my domain http to https and I have already do that with below mention code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

When a user enter domain.com it's automatically redirect to https www.domain.com But when user enter only www.domain.com it's redirect to the http www.domain.com

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This worked for me [Non www to https www redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453412/redirect-to-http-non-www-to-https-www-htaccess/31234149#31234149)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Test without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
# Test for http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
# Redirect to https www
RewriteRule ^ https://www.exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

At your code :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
```

It is a condition for the following rule ; so the rule will be applied only for none `www` request.

Moreover , don't use `R=301` redirection when you test new code unless you make sure that your rules is ok and you could use `R=302` or just `R`.

regardless of your code Put the following code at your main directory `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

If you want to force every request to be `www` you should do this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#this line above will match any request without `https`

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

#the two lines above will exclude none `www` request and force only `www` request unto `https` and the rule will stop here `L`

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# the last two line will exclude any `www` request and force only none `www` into `https`
```