# how to force website to open with www and https with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I am unable to direct my example.in to https://www.example.in
I am using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if 
not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
AcceptPathInfo On
```

I have found this code on stackoverflow but it's not working in my project
my site is on AWS and using virtual host of apache2 php 7.0

It is not forcing www and and i have tried other code .htaccess but if i manually delete the www from url it is not redirected to www .

Comment: # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if 
not - Is this in the same line? It looks like a typo.

Comment: yeah its in same line

Comment: I didn't read your question properly. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17458396/6811933

Comment: i tried that but its not working ...the problem with earlier code as well with this is like when i go to "`http://domain.in`"
 => "`https://www.domain.in`"  ..this is fine .... but if i  go to "`https://domain.in`" =>"`https://domain.in`"  in this case the url redirect is not forcing it to add www

Comment: and if i am going to `http://domain.in/profile/` it is not redirect neither `https` nor for `www`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for support ,

I have solved my problem it was because `ssl` was install on my site and hence in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

I found `default-ssl.conf` file which contains some of setting which was, i guess not allowing me ovveride with `.htaccess` .

but now after adding

```
<Directory /var/www/myfolder > AllowOverride All </Directory>
```

The htaccess is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].