# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with VirtualHost

Tags: apache, https, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I have Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for exampledomain.com. www.exampledomain.com redirects to https://exampledomain.com, but exampledomain.com gives "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page". I use following .conf file for domain in `sites-available` folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain
ServerName mydomain.hu
ServerAlias www.mydomain.hu
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.hu [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.hu
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
Redirect / https://mydomain.hu/
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT:**

Modified `.conf` file with use of answers.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomainamehu
ServerName mydomainame.hu
ServerAlias www.mydomainame.hu
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomainame.hu [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomainame.hu
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
Redirect / https://mydomainame.hu/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomainame.hu
    ServerAlias www.mydomainame.hu
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName mydomainame.hu
 Redirect 301 / https://mydomainame.hu/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName mydomainame.hu
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomainamehu
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: but is the site enabled?

Comment: @DZDomi : Yes, there is same config in sites-enabled folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to HTTP non-www to HTTPS www htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453412/redirect-to-http-non-www-to-https-www-htaccess)

Comment: @Hackerman : I updated question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

VirtualHost must listen on port 443 when using https.

I usually listen on port 80, add a redirect there and then config the docroot in a separate VirtualHost:

```
    #this listens on port 80 and redirects to https
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.hu
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.hu
    Redirect 301 / https://mydomain.hu
    </VirtualHost>

    #this is to avoid "duplicate" traffic on www
    <VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName www.mydomain.hu
     Redirect 301 / https://mydomain.hu/
    </VirtualHost>

    #here is your docroot so you don't get "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page"
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.hu
    DocumentRoot /home/www/whatever
    </VirtualHost>
```

Please note that you should also add access rules and certificates configuration (if needed), otherwise this is not going to work.

Comment: I added these to conf file, changed domain name and docroot, but has same effect, nothing changed.

Comment: if you just added pieces of code I'm afraid it's not going to work, what I see in your last edit is very confusing, I strongly suggest to **replace** a configuration when you are trying with a new one :)

Comment: I see, but if I use only your answer, it is not working, pages are not loading on any urls.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a redirect rule like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.hu
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.hu
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I added it and restarted apache2, but has no effect.