# redirect www to non-www while preserving http or https

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

Here is a link to an almost identical question [htaccess for redirecting non-www to www while preserving http & https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525348/htaccess-for-redirecting-non-www-to-www-while-preserving-http-https?rq=1)

How would this be written for the opposite - I want to redirect www to non-www while preserving http or https, whatever the link may be originally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what worked, after some trial and error:

```
# Make all http use https and force non-www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Sorry for not coming back to post this sooner, I'm learning...

Answer (score 0):

You can have these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: And if it doesn't work as presented, you may have to do some experimentation with the value for %{HTTPS} -- maybe 0 and 1, or http and https, etc. I've heard of the HTTPS environment variable differing among servers, so maybe this will too.

Comment: @user3348276: If it worked for you can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.